# Android Espresso - Negative time - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso

I am trying to setup Espresso on Android Studio (0.8.14). As soon as I copy the file `espresso-1.1-bundled.jar` into my project's libs folder, Android Studio is starting to complain about `IllegalArgumentException: Negative time: Negative time`, and then the project seems stuck in synchronization.

I did not touch yet the `build.gradle` file.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you include much more detail on the error message? It's not clear what you mean when you say it "complains" about an IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: The exceptions are displayed on the Event Log. When I click on one of the exceptions, it popups a dialog : IDE Fatal Error, Exception in plugin Groovy then a stack trace. Others give exception in "Android Studio Core", or exception in "Android Support"

Comment: Can you include much more detail on the error message? It's not clear what you mean when you say it "complains" about an IllegalArgumentException. –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It showed that `Espresso` is still not Gradle-ready. So I used [`Double Espresso`](https://github.com/JakeWharton/double-espresso) the Gradle-friendly port of `Espresso`, and it seems to be working.